# SwiftUI .onOpenURL does not call on physical device

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios-universal-links, openurl

I have implemented Universal link on my app using SwiftUI. The below is the snippet code for implementation.

```
WindowGroup {
  ContentView()
    .onOpenURL { url in
      viewModel.urlFromOnOpenUrl = url
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine on simulator (iOS 14.5). However when I try on physical device (iOS 14.8) the app just launches but `onOpenURL` does not call. Any idea? Thank you.